# Does this volume profile chart mean that people are still holding the stock at those price levels till today?

Tags: investing, trading, trading-volume

Probably the question on Volume Profile is a very basic one, but I am not clear about it. Please look at the following picture.
[image]

The picture shows the chart covering close to 20 years. Right at the bottom, the chart has maximum width or volume accumulated.

Does it mean that people are still holding the stock **at those price levels till today**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The top 3/4 of the image is a line graph of security price over time. Let's say it is stock price in US dollars, just for convenience in this answer. So, we can see how the price of the stock changed from 2003 through the present, about September 2022.

During that same time interval, the bars in the lower 1/4 part of the image show the number of shares traded over that time period, represented by the height of the bars. Your question is,

> Does it mean that people are still holding the stock at those price
> levels till today?

No, it does not mean that. The price of the stock varies over time. The red marker on the right appears to be the most recent price, $405.10. Some people may have purchased the stock in 2021 for nearly $750.00. If they have not sold their shares since then, their marked-to-market value is $405.10 today, even though they purchased it at a higher price in the past.

*You included the x-axis (time in years) for the price history and the volume traded. The y-axis for stock price is visible on the left. You should check to see if there is a y-axis indicating number of shares traded for the lower 1/4 of the graph which shows the historical volume. It would be shorter than the y-axis for stock price.